# Handling duplicate data models names

Tags: c#, json, data-modeling

I'm hooking up to a pretty extensive online service using JSON in C# and have noticed they use the same name with different values (and types).

In creating the JSON models I'm running into an issue where the different models require different value types.

For example.

```
namespace Mylibrary
{
// event 
public class event
{
    public Item item { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

// context
public class context
{
    public Item item { get; set; }
    public string creator { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
}
```

If I rename the above item class I can no longer use the json deserializer.  However, of course I get a compiler error because of the duplicate class name "Item".

There are somewhere above 30 data models that I need to generate for this service.  In looking closer at their schema, this is going to be an issue for over 90% of those models.  The models themselves are very large, the example above is a simplified example of what I'm running into to illustrate the problem.

In thinking about this issue, I'm betting this would be a rather common occurrence. How is this dealt with?

Comment: When serializing to json, class names are not important, they can be different. Property names will be reflected into json.

Comment: So what you're saying then is to possibly prefix the name with the class?  like eventItem or contextItem?

Comment: Yes, you can give different class names, class name is not included in json objects.

Comment: As well as using the built-in Json.NET attributes, Json.NET also looks for the SerializableAttribute (if IgnoreSerializableAttribute on DefaultContractResolver is set to false) DataContractAttribute, DataMemberAttribute, and NonSerializedAttribute and attributes when determining how JSON is to be serialized and deserialized.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm

Comment: @mecek as OP mentions and shows in their question and code, both `Item` classes are different, so not interchangeable.

Comment: @Amit I think you're only confusing OP. Attributes alone aren't going to help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mecek points out, it's the property names that matter, not the class names. So just give the classes unique names:

- `EventItem`
- `ContextItem`

Then you can use `JsonProperty` to rename the properties:

```
public class Context
{
    [JsonProperty("item")]
    public ContextItem Item { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("creator")]
    public string Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you change the property name from item to Item instead of giving jsonproperty?

Comment: @mecek thanks, you're right, I did that the wrong way around. I don't like lowercase names.